# why kivymd file manager error when click on browse button?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i have problem when click on  Browse File  Button for Browse my directory

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

Window.size = (300, 500)

kv = """
ScreenManager:
    HomePage:
    ToolsPage:
    
<HomePage>:
    name:"home"
    MDBoxLayout:
        md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
        orientation:"vertical"
        MDToolbar:
            title:"Camera"
            md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
            specific_text_color: .23 , .22 , .25 , 1
            elevation:10
            left_action_items:[["menu" , lambda x : app_draw.set_state("open")]]
        Widget:
        
                
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id:app_draw
        MDBoxLayout:
            md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
            orientation:"vertical"
            padding:"5dp"
            spacing:"5dp"
            Image:
                source:"nic.JPG"
                
            MDLabel:
                text:"Yousef Jafari"
                font_style:"Subtitle1"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.texture_size[1]
            MDLabel:
                text:"Email : uz.i@gmail.com"
                font_style:"Caption"
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.texture_size[1]
                
            ScrollView:    
                MDList:
                    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                        text_color:.23 , .22 , .25 , 1
                        md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
                        icon:"camera"
                        text:"Open Camera"
                    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                        text_color:.23 , .22 , .25 , 1
                        md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
                        icon:"eye"
                        text:"GoToolsPage"
                        on_press:root.manager.current="tools" 
                    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                        text_color:.23 , .22 , .25 , 1
                        md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
                        text:"Browse File"
                        icon:"folder"
                        on_release: app.file_manager_open()
      
<ToolsPage>:
    name:"tools"
    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color:.98 , .49 , 0 , 1
        orientation:"vertical"
        MDLabel:
            pos:(0, 235)
            text:"ToolsPage"
            halign:"center"
            theme_text_color:"Custom"
            text_color:.23 , .22 , .25 , 1
            font_style:"Subtitle1"
            
            
        MDFlatButton:
            text:"Back to home"
            on_press:root.manager.current="home"
            pos:(190,0)
        
        MDFlatButton:
            text:"About"
            on_release:app.show_dialog()
        


class HomePage(Screen):
    pass
class ToolsPage(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(HomePage(name="home"))
sm.add_widget(ToolsPage(name="tools"))


class MyDemo(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.manager = None

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title="About App Explain", text="This app designed by Yousef Jafari.", size_hint=(.8, None),
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="Close", text_color=[1, 0, 0.2, 1]
                ),
            ],
        )

    def build(self):
        Demo = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Demo

    def file_manager_open(self):
        if not self.manager:
            self.manager = ModalView(size_hint=(1, 1), auto_dismiss=False)
            self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
                exit_manager=self.exit_manager, select_path=self.select_path)
            self.manager.add_widget(self.file_manager)
            self.file_manager.show('/')
        self.manager_open = True
        self.manager.open()

    def show_dialog(self):
        self.dialog.open()

    def select_path(self, path):
        self.exit_manager()
        toast(path)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def events(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keyboard in (1001, 27):
            if self.manager_open:
                self.file_manager.back()
        return True


MyDemo().run()
```

error code :
% (widget, parent))
kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivymd.uix.filemanager.MDFileManager object at 0x0000020BC88509E8>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.modalview.ModalView object at 0x0000020BC88507B8>
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: How are you not getting a SyntaxError? You start the multiline string, but never end it.

Comment: You need not add `self.file_manager` in `ModalView`. Try without ModalView and it will work just fine